# How To resize power indicator plus icons in Ubuntu 16.04(xfce, gnome)

Tags: 16.04, indicator, nvidia-optimus

I have installed prime-indicator-plus for my Optimus laptop.

Unfortunately, the icon displayed is too large for the panel.

How do I resize the icon?

Answer (score 0):

(Originally this was part of the Question - CW'd this to complete the Q&A)

As I installed prime-indicator-plus for my Optimus Laptop, and searched for answers, no luck with the proper solution for my problem. I decided to make a quick-fix explanation of resolving this problem without breaking stuff for my Ubuntu 16.04 on XFCE environment.(same was in Gnome-shell for this distro).

If you have too big/large icons after installing **power-indicator-plus** like I did.

Just follow the instructions below to fix this icon-size bug in a minute.

1. Locate the icons folder for power-indicator-plus or powerindicator(can be different from distro to distro or environments you use).
2. Take a good look at the image format *.svg , *.png etc. and add it to the code example as shown below.
3. Use admin **sudo** privileges in order to change/convert icon file for the given location according to your environment.

For example, my location of the icons and indicator is **/usr/lib/prime-indicator/icons/**

4.

> sudo convert /usr/lib/prime-indicator/icons/prime-indicator-intel.svg -resize 24x24 /usr/lib/prime-indicator/icons/prime-indicator-intel.svg

5. there are 4 icons in the folder so repeat this step for the rest of them(3 icons), just change the file names/format at the source/destination so code from above becomes

sudo convert /usr/lib/prime-indicator/icons/prime-indicator-intel-***symbolic***.svg -resize 24x24 /usr/lib/prime-indicator/icons/prime-indicator-intel-***symbolic***.svg